# AbstractController::DoubleRenderError that shouldn't be

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internal-server-error, respond-to

I've been getting the following error when I hit this destroy method in a my User controller.

> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. 
>   Please note that you may only
>   call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that
>   neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if
>   you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something
>   like "redirect_to(...) and return".):

It's a strange one, because I honestly am only responding once to the call.

Here's my action:

```
def destroy
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  if user.has_role_for? current_client

    # then we remove the role
    user.has_no_roles_for! current_client

    # was that the users only role?
    if user.roles.count == 0
      user.destroy
    end

    respond_with head :ok
  else
    respond_with({:error=>'unauthorised'}, :status => :forbidden)
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding " and return" after the respond_with lines:

```
respond_with head :ok and return 

respond_with({:error=>'unauthorised'}, :status => :forbidden) and return
```

Comment: I've added the 'and return' to the controller, but I'm still getting that same error.

Comment: I don't understand why, but if I change it to one of the *older* `respond_to` blocks the error goes away.

Answer (score 5):

`head(:ok)` doesn't return something you can `respond_with`.  `head :ok` renders a 200 with no body.  `respond_with` renders via the responder some representation of the object you passed into it.  `head` calls `render`, `respond_with` calls `render`, hence the double render error.

You should change that line to just `head :ok`.